# Woocommerce Rest API is not working on my website

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I have created a new API keys in woocommerce with read and write permissions. but i used this API keys in my API functionalities, it's return "Error: Sorry, you cannot list resources. [woocommerce_rest_cannot_view]". Please let me know what i am missing.

We tried some below solutions, but doesn't works.

1. Added the this code "RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]" in htaccess.
2. Updated the website URL in our server.
3. Added the query_string_auth parameter in woocommerce key configuration function.
4. Also test with postman.

Answer (score 0):

try using this code in your htaccess file:

## BEGIN WordPress

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Hi alan, Thanks for your response. We have already tried this. but its not working.